# How to match methods which do not have a specific Annotation in AspectJ

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj, pointcut

I have a custom Annotation called @Invisible.
Now I want to match all calls an a method which DOESN'T HAVE an @Invisible Annotation. How can i do  this? (with annotation style development)

My first try was:

```
@Pointcut("execution(!@my.package.Invisible * some.other.package.execute(..))")
```

but this doesn't seem to work...

In other words: if the method has the Invisible annotation I want to ignore it. Otherwise i want to execute some code with my advice...

Comment: Do you have any other advice on the class before this one? In other words, has the class already been proxied, potentially losing annotations? AFAIK the syntax itself works.

Comment: try something like `execution(* some.other.package.execute(..)) && !@annotation(my.package.Invisible)`

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov According to the [annotation pointcut notebook](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/annotations-pointcuts-and-advice.html) you *should* be able to combine it into a single expression, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Thank you very much :) @KonstantinV.Salikhov's advice works :)

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov: wanna post an answer for user1291235 to accept afterwards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try something like `execution(* some.other.package.execute(..)) && !@annotation(my.package.Invisible)`